# Git merge & adding change id

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

What is the proper way to add change id to a merge commit subsequently?

I merged some changes from master branches, that caused a merged commit that doesn't contain change id. This is not the last commit, so commit --amend doesn't work.

I've tried to use interactive rebase, but I can't find the merge commits among the other commits to rewrite commit message.

How can I solve this? There's a metrhod to avoid these situations?

Thanks,

Hubi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
git rebase -i --preserve-merges
```

or

```
git checkout -b temp SHA1-of-merge
git commit --amend # this is where you change your message
git rebase --onto temp SHA1-of-merge my-branch
```

Just remember that you will need to force push your branch after this and may need to tell anyone that is working on the repo currently.